# Serialize Store C# class in camelCase

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I'm storing data in a Firestore DB using .net. I'm using FirestoreData and FirestoreProperty attributes to control how objects are serialized to the DB. C# propeties, by default, are in PascalCase and I'd like them to be serialized in camelCase. I know I can set the name a property will be serialized in the FirestoreProperty attribute, but it's a really tedious and error proner task. Is there any way to configure Firestore .net client to by default serialize properties in camelCase?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [FirestorePropertyAttribute](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/FirestorePropertyAttribute.cs) defines two constructors. One allows to add a name by providing the parameter `name`:

> The name to use within the Firestore document.

So you can simply set it for a property like

```
[FireStoreProperty("anyCase")]
public string AnyCase{ get; set; }
```

Doing this a silent way is not possible without modifying the underlying type. A possible approach is to implement a reflection based [Document converter](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/datamodel.html#document-converters), changing the property names at runtime. You only need to define the converter once for each data class. Here is a possible approach:

```
//Sample data class
[FirestoreData(ConverterType = typeof(CamelCaseConverter<CustomCity>))]
public class CustomCity
{
    public string Name { get; set;  }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public long Population { get; set; }
}

//Sample data class
[FirestoreData(ConverterType = typeof(CamelCaseConverter<CustomPerson>))]
public class CustomPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set;  }
    public uint Age { get; set; }
}

//Conversion of camelCase and PascalCase
public class CamelCaseConverter<T> : IFirestoreConverter<T> where T : new()
{
    public object ToFirestore(T value)
    {
        dynamic camelCased = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            string camelCaseName =
                char.ToLowerInvariant(property.Name[0]) + property.Name.Substring(1);
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)camelCased)[camelCaseName] = property.GetValue(value);
        }
        return camelCased;
    }

    public T FromFirestore(object value)
    {
        if (value is IDictionary<string, object> map)
        {
            T pascalCased = new T();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                string camelCaseName =
                    char.ToLowerInvariant(property.Name[0]) + property.Name.Substring(1);
                property.SetValue(pascalCased, map[camelCaseName]);
            }

            return pascalCased;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException($"Unexpected data: {value.GetType()}");
    }
```

Comment: I'm lookig for a way to silently do that. Is really tedious and error prone having to set the camel case property name for every property